# Why do I have all of my results twice from my prepared statement?

Tags: php, prepared-statement, sqlsrv

I'm using `sqlsrv_prepare()`/`sqlsrv_execute()` for the first time. Until now, I've been using `sqlsrv_query()`. So far, I'm able to get the data that I need and I'm able to use the data effectively. The problem is that I have each value in my results array twice.

Clearly, I'm doing something to make this happen. Maybe I'm overlooking something obvious, or maybe I don't quite understand how `sqlsrv_prepare()`/`sqlsrv_execute()` work yet.

Here is an example of my PHP:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/javascript");

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "inc/dbconn.php");
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "inc/formaterrors.php");

// array populated from checkbox values
$items = (isset($_GET['checked'])) ? $_GET['checked'] : array();

// holds value of $i in foreach below - $i can't be used in sqlsrv_prepare() since it doesn't exist in this scope
$placeholder = '';

// variable from included dbconn.php file
$connectionOptions['Database'] = 'example_db';
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions)
        or die("Couldn't establish a database connection<br/>" . FormatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));

$query = "
        SELECT
        detail.BILLNO,
        detail.BILLTYPE,
        detail.COMPONENTITEMCODE,
        detail.QUANTITYPERBILL,
        detail.REVISION,
        header.BILLDESC1
        FROM (BM_BILLDETAIL detail
        JOIN BM_BILLHEADER header
        ON (detail.BILLNO = header.BILLNO)
        AND (detail.BILLNO = ?)
        AND (header.REVISION = header.CURRENTBILLREVISION)
        AND (detail.REVISION = header.CURRENTBILLREVISION)
        and (detail.ENGINEERINGCHANGEDELNO = ''))
        ";

$results = array();
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $query, array(&$placeholder));

if(!$stmt)
{
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

foreach($items as $i)
{
        $placeholder = $i;
        if(sqlsrv_execute($stmt))
        {
                while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt))
                {
                        $results[] = $row;
                }
        } else
        {
                die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
}

// diplay results as JSON
echo(var_dump(json_encode($results, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)));
?>
```

And here is an example of my results in JSON:

```
{
        "0": "TRC4009-C005",
        "BILLNO": "TRC4009-C005",
        "1": "",
        "BILLTYPE": "",
        "2": "110500001153-00",
        "COMPONENTITEMCODE": "110500001153-00",
        "3": "1.000000",
        "QUANTITYPERBILL": "1.000000",
        "4": "001",
        "REVISION": "001",
        "5": "TRC4009, 8155, Red 800W",
        "BILLDESC1": "TRC4009, 8155, Red 800W"
    }
```

So I've got `key => value` pairs, which is what I want. I don't want the "numbered" keys though. Only the field name keys, i.e., "BILLNO", "REVISION", etc.

Ultimately, my tool still works like this; however, I don't want to double the number of results that I'm sending/receiving/processing each time. In most cases, this will be executed hundreds or thousands of times and the number of results can vary greatly.

Any help/insight is appreciated.

Comment: For each item in items you are looping through your query results.

Comment: RTM: the default value for the second parameter (**fetchType**) in [**sqlsrv_fetch_array**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php): is _SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH_, which _returns an array that has both associative and numeric keys_.

Comment: Ironically, I've been using sqlsrv_fetch_array($results, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) with sqlsrv_query. Honestly didn't occur to me that this would have been the problem.

Also, I did RTM regarding sqlsrv_prepare()/sqlsrv_execute(), but they both assume manipulating the data, not retrieving it. The manual example that I found for using data retrieved with a SELECT statement was left in the comments and didn't address this. I assumed (incorrectly) that the default value would work as expected. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify a fetch type for `sqlsrv_fetch_array` if you only want to get the text keys. The default fetch type is [`SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php#refsect1-function.sqlsrv-fetch-array-parameters), which is why you're getting both text and numeric keys.

You want to use `sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)` instead.

Comment: This was the solution to my problem. Thanks for the help! I had been tweaking the placement of while() block and rewriting my foreach() for a couple of days, and rereading the PHP man pages for prepared statement functions over to see if I missed anything. Didn't occur to me that I should have been changing that argument the whole time.

Comment: I get how RTM doesn't really work when you're thinking the problem is something it isn't. In cases where something just isn't making sense and "R"ing the "M" hasn't helped, I think two things are really helpful in speeding up the problem solving process. One is to not hang on too tightly to your theory of what the problem is, and the other is to use a step debugger and watch what the code is actually doing as it goes.